# How to send from JAVA String(path of file) to C?

Tags: java, c, multithreading, file

i want to send from java some paths to C.

For example i have a folder that have 4 subfoldes... From java i read the length of them from the code below and it returns me 4.

```
     public static int GetLength(){File file = new File("C:\\Registrations");
           File[] files = file.listFiles(new FileFilter(){
             public boolean accept(File f) {
                 return f.isDirectory();   }});
                  return files.length;}     }
```

Now with a thread i start to call the function that connect with C

```
      public Start(){ Thread listeningThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
        new Match(GetDBNumber());  }  });
        listeningThread.start();}
```

So far all good. Now from **MATCH(int x)** class i want to call a C code and every time give the path of the Main folder each time

```
    *PSEUDOCODE*      public class Match {
                       public Match( int len){
                      System.out.println("subfolders  : "+len);
                      for (i=0; i<len; i++)
                      {     //Some way call C programm (like an exe) 
                            //with the first,second,third,fourth path   
                      }  
                        ....      }
```

The C code that will recieve the path will be look like that...

```
            int main()     {    
            FILE *fp = fopen(FilePATH, "r");
            ...... 
            ......                        
            return 0;                                 }
```

I try with ProcessBuilder but i cant send the path every time with this way...

```
          ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder();
           //receive.exe is the exe that Codeblocks create after built the C code
          p.command("C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TEST\\C\\recieve.exe");  
         try {
             p.start();
             } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("Error");

            }
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you attempt this?  What error messages do you get from both programs?  Also, you don't seem to be passing any parameters to the C program.

Comment: when i attemp this it calls the exe. If i have set before at C code a default path it runs.. But  i want C to read the given path from Java. So if i try this without setting a default path its doesnt work at all...

Comment: When you say the "default path", do you mean the current directory?  The C program should inherit that from the JVM.  I think what you really want is for the Java program to pass the file name as a parameter.

Comment: How will you execute the C code? Do you want to call it directly? Or do you want to start a new process to run it?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Eric Fitzsimmons,
you will need to use JNI to pass a String value from Java to C.

The C part will need to be in a dll that is available to the Java program.

[Wikipedia has a JNI article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)

[Oracle has an in-depth JNI write-up](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/intro.html)

**Edit** Concerning JNI.
If you want to send a value between Java and C,
there are only a few ways to do it.

1. JNI. As stated, Java Native Interface is built for this. This seems to be the best solution.
2. Use an external Data store. Write something to a data store (maybe a file or a database) on one side and read it on the other side (sides being Java and C).
3. Write a stand-alone C program that writes to standard out. Launch that program from within Java. Read what was written in java.  This is not a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on a lot of variables.  I'll assume that you are building the C code and can change how things are passed, so...

Easiest to hardest:

- Pass it in as a command line parameter (only works once per C file execution)
- Write/update a text file on your hard drive that the C program can watch
- Use TCP/IP and send messages over a pre-designated socket
- Build as a shared library or DLL and Use JNI to call the C functions

If you were doing this professionally and this was just the beginning of a larger development effort you'd be wise to look into more professional tooling:

- a message bus (Apache has one called ActiveMQ) is designed to do exactly what you are trying to do (and so much more)
- a shared cache (Hazlecast can connect Java to C++ and nearly everything else and share data freely)
- A shared table in a database that both languages can access.

These are much higher initial investment in time (otherwise free) but they have innumerable features that you could continue to take advantage of as your system grows.

Answer (score -1):

Use jni (Java native interfaces)  Make a c++ .dll file and you can easily pass information between both languages.

Good example/explanation for using jni:
https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html